# How can I clone a GitHub repository, then push it to a new repository as origin?

Tags: git, github

Let's say you have a framework on GitHub and want to use it to create other sites, so you want to:

- clone it locally
- change it
- push it to a new repository

These are the instructions I currently have for this:

- `git clone https://github.com/yourname/framework.git newsite`
- `cd newsite`
- (make changes)
- on Github, create new repository called "newsite"
- `git remote add origin2 https://github.com/yourname/newsite.git`
- `git push -u origin2 master`

I unfortunately have to push to `origin2` otherwise it pushes back to my original framework, which I don't want, of course.

But this causes the problem that I may inadvertently push to origin at some time in the future.

**How can I make my new repository origin?**

Or is there a more straight-forward way to do this when you want to (1) clone a repository, but (2) push it to a different repository?

Comment: [rename origin](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/renaming-a-remote) and then `git remote add origin https://github.com/yourname/newsite.git`.

Comment: Why not remove the old origin remote and add your new one *as origin*? Alternatively the first repo can be set up as a template, giving an option other than forking: https://github.blog/2019-06-06-generate-new-repositories-with-repository-templates/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would want to update both fetch and push URL, pointing to same repo

```
git remote set-url origin <new-repo-url>
```

Below command will set new repository as default repo to **push** only.

```
git remote set-url --push origin <new-repo-url>
```

If need to unset the Push URL setup by above command

```
 git remote set-url --delete --push origin <current-push-URL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to rename remotes if you do a proper clone from the beginning. You can [give a different name to the remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--oltnamegt):

```
git clone -o upstream https://github.com/yourname/framework.git newsite
cd newsite
# (make changes)
# on Github, create new repository called "newsite"
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourname/newsite.git
git push -u origin master
```

PS. `upstream` is a traditional name for such an initial repo.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try forking the original repository into my account on github. I wouldn't even need to change the `remote` value etc.  And then do my changes in the forked repo.

You can accomplish the same final result with **forking** the repo.

https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo

Comment: But then the new repo would show as a fork of the old one, which it sounds like OP is trying to avoid.