# How to read status of git remote - v

Tags: git, github

I start to learn git, I would like to understand git remote -v status.
When I comfirm `git remote -v` some message below is displayed.

How to understand the status of remote repository?

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/user/calendar.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/calendar.git (push)
```

Best regards

Comment: The message says, whenever you are going to fetch/pull ( git fetch/pull ), you would be using (fetch - https://github.com/user/calendar.git) URL . Whenever you would be doing push , you would be using ( push URL - https://github.com/user/calendar.git). Most of the times both URL points to same repo unless you have customer requirements. To change the URL look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085383/how-can-i-clone-a-github-repository-then-push-it-to-a-new-repository-as-origin/59085595#59085595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git remote` just lists remote repositories, without telling you anything about the status of these repositories.

Use `git status` to see the status of your local repository in relation to the remote repository. E.g., this will tell you that you are ahead (local commits not yet pushed to remote) or behind (your local repository is not up-to-date).

With `git fetch`, `git pull`, and `git push` you can interact with the remote repository.

Also make sure to take a look on Git's good manual pages, like `git help remote`, `git help status`, and so on.